# Outlook Addin: What to return in GetCustomUI for Default Menu

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an addin that I wrote for Outlook 2013 that is working as expected. But, when a user right clicks on a contact card, The GetCustomUI method is fired (As expected). But I dont want to display any context menu for the contact card.  I tried returning string.empty and null but I get the following error:

```
the call to getcustomui() for ribbonid microsoft.mso.IMLayerUI Failed
```

Any ideas what I need to return to just display default context menus?

Here is what i have at the moment:

```
   string IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI(string ribbonId)
        {
            if (ribbonId == "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer")
            {
                StringBuilder RibbonXmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                // Removed bussiness logic for question
                return RibbonXmlBuilder.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // What should i return?
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I also tried returning an empty XML ribbon but that didn't work either:

```
return @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?> <customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui""> <ribbon> </ribbon> 
</customUI>";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try unchecking 'Business Contact Manager for Outlook' in the Add-in list.

Comment: Please refer [Remove Business Contact Manager for Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/remove-business-contact-manager-for-outlook-2010-HA010262564.aspx)

Comment: I am using Outlook 2013. Plus, disabling some addin doesn't seem like a good solution. I know this can be resolved in code.